# Inner join on multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables

- tbltask
- tbluser

In `tbluser` I have two columns, `userid` and `username`

Sample data:

```
1     ibrahim
2     nizam
3     shahrukh
4      saddam
```

and in my second table, I have multiple tasks

```
taskid   userid   assignby   assignto
-------------------------------------
1         4           4          2
```

Here saddam assigned a task to nizam

```
2         3           3          1
```

Here shahrukh assigned a task to ibrahim

I have a select command like

```
select userid, assignby, assignto from tbltask where taskid='1'
```

and i am getting this

```
3        3          1
```

now i want to join the table, because instead of i, i want username to be displayed

so answer which i want to display will be

```
shahrukh shahrukh ibrahim
```

how i can join the table?

Comment: This is an extremely basic question. Have you searched at all? If you don't know how `join` works, you may want to study sql a bit more before asking such elementary questions.

Comment: actually i used join but here the complication is i want to fetch data from a single column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the query

```
select t2.username, t3.username, t4.username
from tbltask t1
inner join tbluser as t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid
inner join tbluser as t3 on t1.assignby = t3.userid
inner join tbluser as t4 on t1.assignto = t4.userid
```